# Как сделать метод пригодным для with?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть метод-обертка для загрузки YAML в объект.

```
def load_yaml(path):
    with io.open(path, encoding='utf-8') as fp:
        return yaml.safe_load(fp)
```

Хочу использовать `with` с этим методом:

```
with load_yaml('data.yml') as data:
    pass
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
    ...
    with load_yaml('data.yml) as data:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Что я делаю не так? Какие требования предъявляются к методу, чтобы его можно было использовать с with?

Comment: Описание как делать функции подходящими для with [есть тут](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) для краткости [вот пример](https://image.prntscr.com/image/y3tylRO7Ql2nFHENHpt_QQ.png).

Comment: каким контекстом вы хотите здесь управлять? `yaml.safe_load()` возвращает готовые значения. Чтобы вы хотели, что `__enter__`, `__exit__()` методы делали при входе/выходе из with-блока?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Требования предъявляются не к "методу" (у вас, кстати, это не метод, а обычная функция), а к результату, который возвращает этот "метод".

После with вообще может стоять не только вызов функции, но и абсолютно любое выражение - сначала оно будет полностью вычислено, и уже над его результатом будет совершаться with. И вот как раз к этому результату есть определённые требования.

Для того, чтобы объект можно было использовать в with, у этого объекта должны быть определены специальные методы `__enter__` и `__exit__`. Именно в этих методах вы и объясняете интерпретатору, как он должен открыть контекст работы с этим объектом и потом безопасно закрыть его.

Более подробно вы можете нагуглить по запросу "питон контекстный менеджер" или прочитать здесь:

https://habrahabr.ru/post/186608/#context

https://habrahabr.ru/post/196382/

Answer (score 5):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, var: list):
        self.var = var

    def __enter__(self):
        self.var.append('enter')
        return self.var

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.var.clear()

with A([1]) as ls:
    ls.append(2)
    print(ls)  # [1, 'enter', 2]

print(ls)  # []
```

или

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def func(var: list):
    try:
        var.append('enter')
        yield var
    finally:
        var.clear()

with func([1]) as ls:
    ls.append(2)
    print(ls)  # [1, 'enter', 2]

print(ls)  # []
```